# WSO2ESB, XPath, split values based on a token in SOAP response

Tags: xslt, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP response message which contains a node value 
similar to string `A_B_C_D`. I need to split each 
value based on the underscore (_) and set them in 
separate properties.

I checked with Xpath tokenize function but could not find a
way to get the values like  `array[1], array[2]..` separately.
I also did some reading on XSLT mediator but not sure whether 
it will help me to achieve this.

Please guide me on how to achieve this objective

Thanks

Comment: The XPath tokenize() function is only avaliable in XSLT 2.0. Does your XSLT processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: By referring the WSO2 ESB documentation got to know that I can enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value like "array[1]" but can't apply tokenize directly on soap:Body with ESB 4.8.1 :

```
<property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="MY_VALUE" expression="//soapenv:Body/myNode"/>
<property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="Element1" expression="fn:tokenize(syn:get-property('MY_VALUE'),'_')[1]"/>
```

With this message :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <myNode>A_B_C</myNode>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

property 'Element1' contain : 'A'

Comment: I'm using ESB 4.9.0. and had to enable `<ESB_HOME>\repository\conf\synapse.properties`   file's `synapse.xpath.dom.failover`  attribute and it worked. Thanks a lot.